Stereo potentiometer - 8-pin (4 per side)?
Main volume pot on an old Hitachi stereo amp from the 1990's / maybe early 2000's. Looks just like a normal 6 pin stereo (3 pin per channel) pot, marking says 200Kohms B (linear) taper - but has a 4th pin for each channel. What the dick is this, and how do i replace it???

Is it a center tap?

@Hearth Maybe, what's a center tap, i'm guessing a contact to the middle point of the resistor strip? What would this be used for?

Yes, there are some uses for one but I'm not sure exactly what they are, myself. I know they're most  often seen in audio equipment, though.

Hello, can you add a picture to what you are seeing
